# When use Spawn and Spawn_link?

Tags: erlang

When I need to create a process,I will use the customary spawn bif.But there is one more bif spawn_link that is often used to do the same thing.

So basically when should one use `spawn` and `spawn_link`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Doing `spawn` and then `link` manually is equivalent in operation to `spawn_link`, but it is not equivalent in time; in particular it is not atomic (as in, two independent operations, not a single, indivisible one). If you spawn a process and it dies in its initialization (whatever your `start` or `init` functions do) then it might die *before* the call to `link` completes, and the linked process will never get notified that the process died since it died before it was linked. Oops!

From Joe Armstrong's *Programming Erlang* Ch.13 "Why Spawning and Linking Must be an Atomic Operation":

> Once upon a time Erlang had two primitives, `spawn` and `link`, and `spawn_link(Mod, Func, Args)` was defined like this:

```
spawn_link(Mod, Func, Args) ->
    Pid = spawn(Mod, Func, Args),
    link(Pid),
    Pid.
```

> Then an obscure bug occurred. The spawned process died before the link statement was called, so the process died but no error signal was generated. This bug took a long time to find. To fix this, `spawn_link` was added as an atomic operation. Even simple-looking programs can be tricky when concurrency is involved.

Answer (score 0):

`spawn` just spawns a new process.

`spawn_link` spawns a new process and automatically creates a link between the calling process and the new process. So it can be implemented as:

```
my_spawn_link(Module, Function, Args) ->
    Pid = spawn(Module, Function, Args),
    link(Pid),
    Pid.
```

Comment: It is good to mention, that `spawn_link` is atomic. That is why, you don't want use your own implementation. In case process crashed before `link` is called - parent process won't be notified.

Comment: I only wanted to show what spawn_link did with code sample. Regarding your note that the parent process won't be notified - it is not exactly true. If the calling process is not trapping exits and the child process doesn't exist than link fails with reason noproc and the parent process crashes. So you can trap exceptions with catch construction during link/1 call. Or you can trap exits with process_flag/2 to receive a message in parent process. But nevertheless I think this solutions are beyond this simple example.

Comment: You may want to add some part of your second comment in your reply. To my understanding, `spawn_link` will always let you know how the child process exited, whereas a separate `link` yielding `noproc` is not explaining that.